# What is the best way to prevent component use primeng style

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have some components with primeNG elements.
until now, I haven't added the primeng style to angular.json, and there is a custom CSS for each element.
Now I want to add a new element and use the primeNg style sheet by adding this to angular.json:

```
"./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
"./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
```

adding these lines appears to affect each element of primeNg in all components.
I didn't found an efficient way to apply the style only on the component with the new elements, any ideas?
thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe try to install those css only on the relevant components (in the css file) as below `@import "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css"`